# Quotient of an algebraic group by the connected component containing identity

Tags: algebraic-groups

Suppose $G$ is a finite flat group over scheme $S$, let $G^0$ be the connected component containing identity. Is it true that the quotient sheaf $G/G^0$ is always representable by a group scheme over $S$? If so, is it always flat over $S$?

Comment: I'm not so sure. Perhaps it depends on what you mean by $G^0$. Consider for example $\mu_p$ over $\mathbf Z_p$. The special fibre of this is connected and the generic fibre is not. So do you want $G^0$ to be the entire special fibre and just the identity in the generic fibre? This I guess is a finite non-flat group scheme. I don't think the quotient will exist in this case---will it? I certainly can't believe that the quotient can be flat, in any case.

Comment: [The reason I ask is that when $S$ is a DVR sometimes $G^0$ is used to mean something else, at least in the $p$-divisible group case]

Comment: If $S$ is spec of henselian local ring (e.g., complete local noeth) then $G^0$ means the unique open and closed subscheme containing the identity section, but (as Kevin notes) its formation doesn't commute with non-local base change (e.g., passage to generic fiber over complete dvr). It's a subgp scheme. In general if $G$ is a finite loc. free comm. gp scheme over a scheme $S$ and $H$ is a finite loc. free closed subgp scheme then the fppf quotient sheaf $G/H$ is always reptble. Nice exercise to prove the dual map $D(G) \rightarrow D(H)$ is fppf, and that dual of its kernel does the job.

Comment: As a separate example, it is proved in Messing's thesis that if $G \rightarrow S$ is a finite loc. free commutative group scheme of $p$-power order with $p$ locally nilpotent on $S$ and if the fibers $G_s$ have identity component whose order is locally constant in $s \in S$ then there exists a unique finite loc. free closed $S$-subgroup $G'$ in $G$ such that $G'_s = G_s$ for all $s \in S$; often this $G'$ is denoted as $G^0$. An interesting example is an $\mathbf{F}_p$-scheme $S$ and $G = A[p^n]$ for $A \rightarrow S$ an abelian scheme whose fibers have constant $p$-rank (e.g., all ordinary).

Comment: I see, so the naive definition of the unique open and closed subscheme containing the identity section for $G^0$ is not interesting over a general base scheme because it's not going to be radical. But over an artinian scheme it's still going to work! That makes a lot of sense, thanks Kevin and Brian!

Comment: Dear Taisong: There is a more fundamental problem with the topological connected component of the identity section over a general base (suppose even connected): since its formation doesn't commute with base change to fibers, there's no reason for it to be a subgroup scheme in general. (I don't have an explicit counterexample, but I am sure that such counterexamples must exist.) The case of a henselian local base is special because one can relate connectedness properties of the topology of the special fiber to that of the entire space for finite schemes over the local henselian base.